# Mat-progress-bar. Listen to upload progress. Angular

Tags: angular, progress-bar

This function initializes a request to a backend and works with a result:

```
startUpload(): void {
        this.upload().subscribe(uploadResp => {
                if (uploadResp) {
                    // grab progress value + grab response data (event.body)
                }
        })
}

upload(): Observable<any> {
        return this.apiService.createDataWithProgressTracking(/*path, data*/);
}
```

There is a request for uploading `data` to a backend + tracking progress value:

```
createDataWithProgressTracking(path: string, data): Observable<any> {
        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', path, data, { reportProgress: true });
        return this.http.request(req).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => this.getUploadProgress(event)),
            share(),
            last(),
            catchError((error: any) => {
                return this.handleError(error);
            })
        );
}
```

Here is how I get the progress value. But I have doubts how correctly return the progress value to work with it in `startUpload()`

```
getUploadProgress(event: HttpEvent<any>): Observable<any> {
        switch(event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                return of(progress);

            case HttpEventType.Response:
                return event.body;
        }
}
```

**QUESTION**

How to get `progress` value from the response correctly?